# Python Urllib keyerror

Tags: python, urllib, keyerror

I want to count all the words from a particular url

```
import urllib.request
url = 'http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt'
fhand = urllib.request.Request(url)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(fhand)
counts = dict()
for line in resp:
    words = line.split()
    print (words)
    for word in words:
        counts[word] = counts[word] +1
print (counts)
```

---

I am getting an error while running this:
[b'But', b'soft', b'what', b'light', b'through', b'yonder', b'window', b'breaks']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Hello/Exercise.py", line 13, in 
    counts[word] = counts[word] +1

### **KeyError: b'But'**

Why is b' being appended with every word or with every line? If I read from a file using same code, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like every day there is a question whose answer is `defaultdict`.

```
import urllib.request
from collections import defaultdict

url = 'http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt'
fhand = urllib.request.Request(url)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(fhand)
counts = defaultdict(int) # pass a default type in, int() == 0
for line in resp:
    words = line.split()
    print (words)
    for word in words:
        counts[word] = counts[word] +1
print (counts)
```

When using a regular dictionary, `count[word]` is not yet defined and will throw a `KeyError`. A simple implementation of `defaultdict` might look something like:

```
class defaultdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, default_type, *args, **kwargs):
        # this allows for the regular dictionary constructor to be used
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) 
        self._type = default_type

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        except KeyError:
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, self._type())
            return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do that, but it should work in roughly the same way. The default implementation of `__setitem__` will then implicitly reference the new definition of `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add to it when it doesn't exist yet. For example.

```
counts = {}
counts["test"] = counts["test"] + 1 # counts["test"] does not exist...
```

Because `"test"` is not yet in `counts`, it will raise a KeyError.

The simple solution is to check and see if it is in there. If it isn't, assign it to 1:

```
import urllib.request
url = 'http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt'
fhand = urllib.request.Request(url)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(fhand)
counts = dict()
for line in resp:
    words = line.split()
    print (words)
    for word in words:
        counts[word] = counts[word]+1 if word in counts else 1
print (counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue.
I was adding as a list though I declared as dictionary.

For dictionary, I tried

counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) +1

and it worked.

Comment: This works because `.get`  doesn't throw a `KeyError`; it takes a second argument `default` for when the dictionary doesn't contain the key, or returns `None` if no second argument is passed.